# How do I call e.target.value only once?

Tags: reactjs

How do I call e.target.value only once?
What to do in situations where you don't want event.target.value to fire every character, but fire only once, when the user stops typing?

```
  const [text, setText] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (e) => { // 5 calls (5 characters)
    let resultText = e.target.value;
    setText(resultText);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{text}</p>
      <input onChange={handleChange} /> // "react" 5 characters
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: How do you detect that the user finished the typing?

Comment: Look for debounce function or create some sort of timer that restarts on every keyPressedUp and once completed triggers an another function

Answer (score 0):

You need to Debounce the event handler to prevent it being fired multiple times.
You can use the [Lodash debounce function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce). This function will make sure that your event is only called after a certain period of time, even if it's fired multiple times.

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

export function MyComponent() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(null);

  // debounced event handler that is only called again
  // after its first call after 1 second
  const debouncedHandler = useCallback(
    debounce((e) => {
      let resultText = e.target.value;
      setText(resultText);
    }, 1000),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{text}</p>
      <input onChange={debouncedHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a debounce function. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) library has a very good one, or you can implement it yourself. It delays invoking your handler until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked. What it means is that you can set like 1-second delay and your handler will only be fired 1 second after the user stopped typing.

```
const handleChange = useCallback(_.debounce((e) => {
    let resultText = e.target.value;
    setText(resultText);
  }, 1000), []);
```

On the other hand, it can be annoying for the user to not see what they are typing until they stop.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve your problem i have used an if check to see if text state has 1 character.As soon as it saves one character it stops adding other characters to e.target.value and also to the state.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [text, setText] = useState("");
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
   // 5 calls (5 characters)
   // Checks the length of the string if it is below 5 it will add it to the state
        if (text.length < 5) {
          let resultText = e.target.value;
          setText(resultText);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <p>{text}</p>
          <input onChange={handleChange} /> // "react" 5 characters
        </div>
      );
    }
```